# Can't open Google Takeout backup files on Android

Tags: zip, google-takeout

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 phone. Recently, I've downloaded some Google Takeout backup files I created at [the Google Takeout site](https://takeout.google.com/), to my Android device. Here are some screenshots.

[image: picture 1]
[image: picture 2]

However, as the attached images demonstrate, I was unable to open the files on my Android device.

How can I open them on Android directly?

Comment: I think you're supposed to that in a desktop computer (Windows, maybe others). But depending on the file type you selected when exporting there are apps that can unpack it, especially if it was `.zip`. Most mainstream phones' File Managers support it natively. What you can or can't do with the extract content in an Android phone I'm not sure. For the other format just google "tgz file extractor android".

Comment: The screenshots unfortunately don't show the file type. But if it is a ZIP file then the ZIP file will be most likely in ZIP64 format as it is larger than 2GB. Not every ZIP capable program is ZIP64 capable. When searching for a program how open the ZIP file with then make sure it has ZIP64 support.

Answer (score 1):

These are .zip files by default, so you'll need an app that can handle this type of file. There are [plenty available](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=zip%20files&c=apps&hl=en_US&gl=US) on the Play Store, most of which can handle the .zip and .tgz files that can be output by Takeout. I've preferred [X-plore File manager](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=xplore&c=apps&hl=en_US&gl=US) for a long time, because it allows you to browse inside them without un-zipping, but I'm sure there are plenty of others with this functionality too.